# Why is Asta's hair in devil union form black?

Tags: black-clover

Why is Asta's hair, in devil union form, black in color if both Liebe's and Asta's hair, in normal form, is gray?

Answer (score 2):

In Chapter 271 when Asta first tries Devil Union, Nacht explains that the black color is the power of the devil leaking out. Even after he trains and manages to achieve the proper union state, it's possible this power is making his hair look blacker than it is.

But in a general sense, this is just to make the powered up state visually distinct. Yuno normally has black hair, but his hair turns light when he uses the wind spirit's power.